# How to remove Maven Wrapper from Ubuntu command line?

Tags: shell, maven, ubuntu, command, wrapper

I used this command to add maven wrapper to the current project:

`$ mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper`

but `- cd` to the wrong project folder.

How can I remove `mvnw` and `mvnw.cmd` in that folder from Ubuntu command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `rm mvnw mvnw.cmd` from that folder should remove those two files from the directory.